# Other way to synchronize method

Tags: java, synchronization

How to synchronize method in java other than using synchronized keyword?

Comment: why are you looking for another solution?

Comment: iam looking for alternative(its the part of learning)

Comment: When you place synchronized on a method, its the object you lock not the method.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could use the `java.util.concurrent.locks` package, especially Lock interface:

```
Lock l = ...; 
l.lock();
try {
    // access the resource protected by this lock
} finally {
    l.unlock();
}
```

See [here](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/Lock.html).

Answer (score 2):

Depends on you concrete needs.

See [Java concurrent package](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/package-summary.html) for higher level synchronization abstractions. Note that they may still use `synchronized` underneath ...

Answer (score 1):

you can use Lock classes provided in java.util.concurrent.locks package

see http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/index.html?java/util/concurrent/locks/Lock.html

Answer (score 1):

That depends on what you're trying to do. Are you looking out of curiosity or is there a specific reason?

If you are trying to speed up your multi-threaded methods, try synchronizing or locking around specific sections, or avoiding the threading issues altogether; make shared data `final`, make static (non-shared) data `ThreadLocal`, use the atomic types from `java.util.concurrent.atomic`, use concurrent collections (from the `java.util.concurrent` packages), etc.

BTW, the `java.util.concurrent` stuff is only available in Java5 onwards, though there as a project to back-port the packages for Java 1.4 at http://backport-jsr166.sourceforge.net/

I'd recommend the the book 'Java Concurrency in Practice', by Brian Goetz.

Answer (score 1):

You could also use [@Synchronized](http://projectlombok.org/features/Synchronized.html) from [Project Lombok](http://projectlombok.org) to generate a private field that will be used as the lock for your method.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a synchronized block inside your method.  This can be useful if you want two methods belonging to the same class to be synchronized separately.

```
private Object guard = new ...
public method(){
   synchronized(guard){
      \\method body
      ...
   }
}
```

Although in most cases this suggests that you should really break your class up.