# What's the difference between a synchronized block and a condition variable lock?

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronized

```
...
lock.lock()
try{
...
}
finally{
lock.unlock()}
...
```

I noticed that this doesn't insure absolute mutual exclusion where as synchronized always does, so what are exactly the differences between both?

```
 import java.util.concurrent.locks.Condition;
import java.util.concurrent.locks.Lock;
import java.util.concurrent.locks.ReentrantLock;

    public class Guys extends Thread{



            public static void go()throws InterruptedException{

                final Lock lock = new ReentrantLock();



                lock.lock();
                try{



                System.out.println("global " + main.global);



                main.global = main.global + 100;
                }
                finally
                {


                lock.unlock();
                }


            }






        public void run(){

            try{



                for(int i = 0; i <1; i++)
                {
                    System.out.println(this);




                    go();



                }
            } catch(InterruptedException e)
            {
                System.out.println("Interrupted Exception caught");
            }

        }


    }
```

My threads are sharing a single resource. Only synchronized works in this case.

Comment: Which platform is this?

Comment: oh sorry.. it's on java

Comment: I thought it would work, because it was suggested as an alternative, but obviously it's not the same thing http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5482981/other-way-to-synchronize-method

Comment: What is `lock`? Show us an SSCCE (http://sscce.org/).

Comment: @NPE: lock is likely a concrete implementation of [the Lock interface](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/Lock.html) such as a ReentrantLock. This is part of the [concurrent package](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/package-summary.html). To the OP, synchronized without specifying what you're synchronizing on will synchronize on `this`, while `lock.lock()` will synchronize on the Lock object -- a big difference, especially if there will be multiple instances of `this` type. Myself, I prefer using Locks.

Comment: But you can't call lock() on this.

Comment: This question is basically too vague to answer at the moment. It's not clear what you're trying to achieve, or what `lock` is, etc. As NPE said, we really need a short but complete program here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're creating a new Lock object with every invocation of the method so each thread locks on a different object.

Take out this line

```
final Lock lock = new ReentrantLock();
```

Outside the method making it a class member and it should work correctly.

@Edit: ok more in-depth explanation:

Making a method synchronized protects it with a lock on an object just like you'd do it with a Lock object yourself. If it's a non static method the lock is done on "this" object. Since you have a static method here the lock will be on the object representing your Guys class. There is one such object so there will be only one lock to be obtained. If one thread holds the lock others have to wait.

What you are doing here is creating a new Lock object on every invocation of go() method therefore each thread calling the go() method acquires a different lock which defends you from nothing because only that thread can call lock.lock() on it (as I said other threads will invoke lock() on their own instances of Lock).

Taking this Lock variable out of the method and making it a class variable will mean that all the threads invoking the go() method will try to acquire the same lock - similar to what synchronized does.

@Edit2: to show it more vividly it is like when there is a group of people and only the person holding a stick can speak. All is ok when there is only 1 stick (which is the case with synchronized method or a shared Lock object). But obviously when it is a group of Polish people (editorial note I am Polish so I can make fun of my own people) everyone will bring their own stick with them (and it is similar with your new ReentrantLock() here). This will result in everyone speaking at the same time. And obviously everyone will be like "omg but I have a stick, I have the full right to speak now!".

Comment: So only synchronized will work in this case? I can't make a global lock or anything, so I really don't see any solution.

Answer (score 0):

`synchronnized` block are some useful but non customizeable way to grant that only one thread can access critical code block. Let's review some `lock` objects that give you benefits over synchronized block:

<strike>**Reenterability** - think about synchronous block inside recursion. Are you sure that it is not failed? There [ReentrantLock](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/ReentrantLock.html) will help you</strike>

**ReadWrite locks** - assume that you have 1000 readers to some Map but only 1 writers. The big optimization can be taken if readers can read simultaneously, but locks are taken only for writer. Then `try..finally` with [ReadWriteLock](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/ReadWriteLock.html) gives you big benefit

Comment: `synchronized` blocks *are* reentrant. `Lock`s *may* be reentrant.